# Why won't printf output a large array?

Tags: arrays, c, printf

We have a project to make a Minesweeper game using tables (arrays) but when I was trying to print the border, it won't let me print it if `m & n` variables are big as `m = 16` and `n = 18` or greater leaving the console completely empty.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int m, n, i, j;
    m = 16;
    n = 18;

    int MainTable[m - 1][n - 1];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            MainTable[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", MainTable[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}
```

But when I lower the variables to `m = 8` and `n = 8` it will work as intended. I think it has to do with some kind of limit to `printf`'s ability.

Can somebody help me understand what is wrong as a way to fix it?

Comment: `int MainTable [m-1][n-1];` ==> `int MainTable [m][n];` otherwise you will try to access inexistent elements of the array in the loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you access out of your array with an undefined behavior, replace

```
int MainTable [m-1][n-1];
```

by

```
int MainTable [m][n];
```

or stop one index before in your loops but this is a non readable way to do

Each dimension you give when you define your array is the number of elements, not the value of the higher valid index

Out of that `int main(...` rather than `void main(...`

Comment: I thought I could not access out because of statement i<m but it seems like i was wrong thank you very much for you help

Comment: @ChristopherKomninos with the dimension D the valid indexes are 0..D-1, checking `i<D` is valid ... but supposing the size is D but not D-1 as you did

Comment: @ChristopherKomninos also `ìnt main()` rather than `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

This came a little late , but it's because you have declared an array with 15 lines and 17 columns each line .

```
    int MainTable [m-1][n-1];
```

then you tried to print the array with 16 lines and 18 columns

```
 for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%d ",MainTable [i][j]); 
    }
    }
```

so to fix your code you need to change the array with 16 lines and 18 columns each line

```
    int MainTable [m][n];
```

or simply print in the correct range

```
for(i=0;i<m-1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        printf("%d ",MainTable [i][j]); 
    }
    }
```

Now moving to this part (the main reason i replied) , using two variables to limit the size of an array may lead to a lot of issues such as losing the ability to initialize an array (or set values to it ) from the beginning

for that we you should use constant values such as this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define m 16
#define n 18
void main() {
int i,j;

int MainTable [m-1][n-1];
```

with #define you have earned memory . it will simply replace every existance of m and n in your code with the given value . also that will lead us to instead of initialize your code with this

```
 for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        MainTable [i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

you can skip it to this

```
int MainTable [m-1][n-1] = {0};
```

Comment: With optimizations enabled it won't make any difference.